# Chrome Extension - Console Log not firing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, console.log

I'm starting to learn to make my own Chrome Extensions, and starting small.
At the moment, I'm switching from using the `alert()` function to `console.log()` for a cleaner development environment.

For some reason, `console.log()` is not displaying in my chrome console logs.  However, the `alert()` function is working just fine.

Can someone review my code below and perhaps tell me why `console.log()` isn't firing as expected?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sandbox",
  "version": "0.2",
  "description": "My Chrome Extension Playground",
  "icons":  { 
        "16": "imgs/16x16.png", 
        "24": "imgs/24x24.png", 
        "32": "imgs/32x32.png", 
        "48": "imgs/48x48.png" 
        },

  "background": { 
         "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
        },


  "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My Fun Sandbox Environment",
            "default_icon": "imgs/16x16.png"
        },

  "permissions": [
        "background",
        "storage",
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ] 
}
```

**js/background.js**

```
function click(e) {
  alert("this alert certainly shows");  
  console.log("But this does not");
}

// Fire a function, when icon is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(click);
```

As you can see, I kept it very simple.  Just the manifest.json and a background.js file with an event listener, if the icon in the toolbar is clicked.

As I mentioned, the `alert()` is popping up nicely, while the `console.log()` appears to be ignored.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to open the "_generated_background_page.html" in extension page (chrome://extensions/)

Comment: that worked!  I forgot to mention I was right-clicking on the browser tab, selecting `inspect-element`, and searching in that instance.